# LLVM native code generation

Tags: haskell, code-generation, llvm

How is native code generated using llvm?

If it is possible, can it be done using a Haskell binding?

upd: I mean generate code not in memory, I mean how to generate code and for example save it to file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LLVM is a compiler infrastructure that generates native code by processing its [internal language](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) — produced by compilers as textual source or an in-memory representation — through a wide variety of optimisations and transformations before converting and linking it into the final native code. So, yes, LLVM can generate native code; in fact, that's its primary purpose.

There is a [binding to the LLVM library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm) for Haskell. You can produce LLVM bitcode files with [`writeBitcodeToFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/llvm/latest/doc/html/LLVM-Core.html#v%3awriteBitcodeToFile); [`llvm-ld`](http://llvm.org/cmds/llvm-ld.html) can then link those into native code.